# how to add fckeditor to a dynamically creating form in php?

Tags: php, fckeditor

I am creating a dynamic form in php. And i want to add fckeditor to this dynamic form.
so any idea about to add fckeditor to a dynamically creating form in php???

---

So how can i post values from the fckeditor. That is my actual problem

When i assign text to fckeditor statically using its value property then it stores that in database but when i entered text in fckeditor after execution then it does not save it in database.

What is the problem?

Comment: the same way you output the html, echo it. i guess there's more to the question - some where

Answer (score 0):

have you added fckeditor on your web page? don't you know how to post form values and save to mysql database?

you have to post fckeditor value then save to mysql database

Answer (score 0):

@Ahmwad Nawaz: I use the jQuery plugin for [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) (next version of FCKEditor). See usage here: http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/CKEditor/#tab-Usage.

If you still wish to create and instantiate the `textarea` within PHP, when you download the editor it should contain a `_samples` directory and within that a `php` directory with several samples in it to show you how to do it.

Comment: Is not **next** (newer instead) version of FCKEditor, the developer is Brazilian, and he did not aware FCK=sounds like F*CK, and decided to rename the entire package